# Errors with Selenium and Python and Using Chrome Driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**EDIT:** The code is failing after the first line. I have reinstalled Google Chrome, reinstalled the webdriver, and selenium, however I can't seem to resolve the issue. The screenshot is attached. I'm also [Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sqg2.png) MacOS. **Thank you @Dimitri T and @Omer Tekbiyik for your assistance thus far!**

*I am trying to use selenium and python using chromedriver, but I can't seem to get past a string of errors. I've troubleshooted using just about everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

```py
from selenium import webdriver
# os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
# browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
# browser.get("https://newclasses.nyu.edu/portal/site/a3aa9fb7-82a4-4b7e-# ac96-2e50b60cbbbc/tool/b81f9600-6b1e-452f-9e1a-ea4af0d2fb4a/main")

# title = browser.title
# print(title)
```

Here is the Code I have tried. 
I've also tried this...

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# browser.get("https://newclasses.nyu.edu/portal/site/a3aa9fb7-82a4-4b7e-# # ac96-2e50b60cbbbc/tool/b81f9600-6b1e-452f-9e1a-ea4af0d2fb4a/main")

# title = browser.title
# print(title)
```

I expect it to launch a webpage, however, I just get a string of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trapbookpro/Downloads/PythonLoginScripts/yes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/Users/trapbookpro/Downloads/PythonLoginScripts/copy.py", line 10, in <module>
    lst1()
```

Comment: Maybe something to do with the python being a different version? I've been having the same

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's start clean. Install [Selenium package](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) using [PIP](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

   ```
   pip install -U selenium
   ```
2. Download and install [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
3. Download [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) (make sure to choose the matching version for your Chrome browser version)
4. Amend your code to look like:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   browser = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
   browser.get(
       "https://newclasses.nyu.edu/portal/site/a3aa9fb7-82a4-4b7e-ac96-2e50b60cbbbc/tool/b81f9600-6b1e-452f-9e1a-ea4af0d2fb4a/main")
   title = browser.title
   print(title)
   browser.quit()
   ```
5. That's it, your script should be working now:

   [image]

More information including installation, configuration steps and a sample project: [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python)

Comment: I uninstalled selenium, uninstalled chrome, and reinstalled the chromedriver. The chrome driver ends in .90 and my chrome version ends in .100, but everything else is the same. @Dimitri T, I don't think it's working past my first line: ```from selenium import webdriver```. It's immediately throwing the error and I don't know why. I'm not even able to get to the code! This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add driver path like:

```
driver_path = r'your driver path'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
```

and get titles like :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'your path'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get("https://newclasses.nyu.edu/portal/site/a3aa9fb7-82a4-4b7e-ac96-2e50b60cbbbc/tool/b81f9600-6b1e-452f-9e1a-ea4af0d2fb4a/main")
title = browser.title
print(title)
```

Output :

```
NYU Login
```

Comment: Even when I do that, ```from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'/Users/trapbookpro/Downloads/PythonLoginScripts/Drivers/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)``` I still get the same error. That's the exact path of it. Am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: Upon further examination, even if I type the first line ```from Selenium import webdriver```, I  get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem! After experimenting with Jupyter I found a way to make this script work!

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U selenium
sudo -H pip3 install urllib3
sudo easy_install selenium
```

This works perfectly and also running my script in python3 allowed me to successfully run this script. Thank you, everyone, for everything!